# Uninstall 'not installed' TexStudio

Tags: apt, uninstall

I have installed TexStudio from a .deb package downloaded from the TexStudio web page. When I started studio, graphics was corrupted, so I decided to install another LaTeX editor (Texmaker). I installed Texmaker from Ubuntu Software Center. I wanted to remove TexStudio too, so I've clicked on the menu "Installed" and TexStudio nowhere. So I tried it through apt-get remove and the message `Package 'texstudio' is not installed, so not removed` was shown up. I have tried it with right mouse button click on application shortcut and chose "Uninstall", but nothing works. Texstudio shortcut is annoying, texstudio is runnable but not uninstallable. Is there a way to uninstall application correctly? Thank you.

Comment: Try `apt list --installed 'texstudio*'`. Can you find anything?

Comment: Yes, it found `texstudio-qt4/now 2.12.6-2 i386 [installed,local]`. Awesome, `apt-get remove texstudio-qt4` worked. Thank you. Please reformulate your comment as an answer, and I'll mark it as the correct one.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The actual package name may contain some suffix (less probably a prefix, too), try searching for packages *beginning* with the string `texstudio`:

```
apt list --installed 'texstudio*'
```

Then remove the found package(s), e.g.:

```
sudo apt remove texstudio-qt4
```